# Styling two divs using display block to not have a double border between them and cause the next item to go to a new line

Tags: css

I have two letters I want to display next to each other with borders around them:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="status">C</div>
<div class="status">A</div>

<a>A link</a>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.status{ 
    display: block;
    float:left; border: 3px solid gray;   
    font-size: 3em
}
```

There is also an anchor following them.

Ok so this produces C and A with borders around them but as you can see:

http://jsfiddle.net/FgqHa/1/

The border between them is made up of the border of the C and the border of the D. Hence it is twice as thick between them ie. 6px.

Could someone suggest the best way to make it so the border between the two is only 3px?

Also the link is supposed to appear on the next line but is to the right of the letters. How to force it to the next line?

Comment: Will this always be the layout? Two elements with borders? If so you can use CSS3 pseudo selectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for a dynamic list of elements: [your edited jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FgqHa/4/).

The magic is the pseudo class `:first-child` (`:last-child` is also possible).

Comment: ah cool, Ive been using css for years and never used them haha.  I just always do it the way I described in my answer lol.

Comment: @r3bel, thanks that solves the border and is a really good solution. Just doesn't force the link to the next line though.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `border-right:1.5px` on the left one and `border-left:1.5px` on the right one, or only give one of the two an inner border.  Either that or possibly set `margin-left:-3px` on the right one (not sure if this would work).

Thinking about it I would probably have `border-right:0px` on the left one and `border-left:3px` on the left one just incase the browser decides to do something weird with the half pixels.